# Поиск и изменение вьюхи в RecycleView по содержимому

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

```
@Subscribe
public void onCreateTaskEvent(final RateTaskEvent event) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.feed_recycler_view);
}
```

Подписан на событие прибытия кастомного эвента. Во фрагменте есть RecycleView с кастомными вьюшками в роли элементов. Event содержит строку CUSTOM_ID = "example", как найти в RecycleView конкретную вьюху с CUSTOM_ID = "example" и поменять, например, её цвет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В onBindViewHolder адаптера вам надо менять цвет в зависимости от некоего значения, содержащегося в списке данных адаптера. Т.е. что-то типа

```
if(someListWithData.get(position).someValue == someConstant)
{
    //тут один цвет назначается
}
else
{
    //тут другой цвет назначается
}
```

После этого изменения адаптера вам надо при принятии события изменить значение нужного элемента списка данных адаптера и уведомить адаптер об изменениях, заставив его перерисовать элементы методом `notifyDataSetChanged()` или `notifyItemChanged(int position)`.

---

Главное - не пытаться напрямую достучаться до конкретной вьюхи адаптера в попытке её изменить. Вы должны лишь менять некое условие, по коему адаптер определяет что и как ему отображать.

Comment: Да, спасибо, это и было нужно

Comment: @AlexanderBorodin, если ответ решает поставленную в вопросе задачу, то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа (но не раньше 15 мин после публикации вопроса)